# Передача в шаблон типов аргументов и указателя на функцию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Для методов класса A, e.g.:

```
class A{
    int foo(int, bool, int); 
}
```

Требуется генерировать прокси-функцию в этом же класса А:

```
void proxy(packed_value* output, packed_value* input)
```

Где для **A.foo** будет сгенерировано, e.g.:

```
void proxy(packed_value* output, packed_value* input) {
    pack(output, 
        foo(unpack(input[0])/*int*/, unpack(input[1])/*bool*/, unpack(input[2])/*int*/));
}
```

Все это должен делать метод класса **A::add_method_to_list** и сохранять прокси-метод в контейнер:

```
template<class Ret, class ...Args>
void add_method_to_list(std::string name, Ret(A::*method)(Args...)) {
    ...
    some_struct proxy_method = {name, &addin::proxy</*method*/???>};
    methods_.push_back(proxy_method);
}
```

---

Есть генерация метода:

```
template<???>
void proxy(packed_value* return_value, packed_value* params) {
    proxy_impl<???>(return_value, params, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}

template<???, std::size_t ...indexes>
void proxy_impl(packed_value* return_value, packed_value* params, const 
std::index_sequence<indexes...> &)
{
    pack(return_value, this->METHOD(unpack<std::decay_t<Args>>(params[indexes])...));       
}
```

---

Вопрос: как передать в шаблон генерации прокси-метода информацию как о сигнатуре метода (Args...) так и ссылку на сам метод (METHOD)? Прокси методы будут дергаться по имени другой системой.

Comment: Может `template <auto METHOD>` подойдет? И передавать в него указатели на методы вроде `&A::method`.

Comment: Что такое `packed_value`, `pack`, `unpack`?  Приведите полноценный пример.

Comment: @VTT packed_value - структура хранящая вспомогательную информацию и данные, pack/unpack функции, которые упаковывают/распаковывают стандартные типа (bool, int, float etc) в/из этой структуры.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как из template <auto METHOD> я вытяну в теле аргументы метода METHOD? (Args...)

Comment: Делаете вложенный пустой шаблонный класс с параметром `<auto METHOD>`. Делаете для него частичную специализацию (см ссылку ниже) и помещаете код, которому нужны типы аргументов, в нешаблонную статическую функцию этой специализации. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87e61d04cb227194 Заметьте, что нужно две специализации, для константных и неконстантных методов.